# Media Live channels takes ages from Idle to Running

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-media-live

My setup is the following :

- I have a channel that takes an **HLS** input and pushes it to a specific twitch channel
- The output group doesnt change
- The input however **does** change every day and i'm performing an input switch (picking a different HLS playlist) and then i start the channel
- Once the stream is over i stop the channel

I have a node application that constantly checks which **HLS** input should be scheduled and automatically switches the input at a give time and immediatly after it starts the channel

My problem is that even if everything is working as expected the channel sometimes takes **5-8 minutes** to go from Idle to running

It seems to be completely random, sometimes it takes less than 50 seconds (which would be more than acceptable) but having to wait 5 minutes or more is silly.

I also tried to buy a reservation for the input (following the "View matched reservation offerings" suggested by AWS) but nothing changed at all... Starting time are still random and more often than not they take several minutes to start the stream.

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately MediaLive does not offer an SLA for channel start times.

When a channel is started, MediaLive spins up a stack of resources in the back end as per the channel configuration and in some cases, it can take up to 10 minutes to start.

Input reservations do not affect the channel start time. A reservation is a one-year commitment to a particular input or output configuration and applies to the cost of processing input. (1)(2).

Outside of preemptively anticipating a wait time of approximately 10 minutes in your workflow, there isn't a means of controlling the start time however this may be worth submitting as feedback.

1. Working with reservations in AWS Elemental MediaLive : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/reservations.html
2. Input and output reservations : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/input-output-reservations.html